# If you delete a contract on NEAR, can you still see the transaction history of that contract?

Tags: nearprotocol

With near-sdk you have the option to delete a contract. How can you go back to see all the transactions this contract had?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the NEAR explorer and the accountId of the contract you deleted, you can see the history of the contract. https://explorer.near.org/